# How to find the dimensions of a (2,3 or if possible an n)dimensional slice in golang and verify if its a matrix?

Tags: matrix, go

For example : `[][]float64{{11, 5, 14, 1}, {11, 5, 14, 1}}` has dimensions `[2,4]`.

If this is passed to a function then what is the most efficient way to find the dimension here?

Thanks

Comment: I am guessing you are referring to the semantics in a different way. I am new to golang but in every other language the dimension [2,4] seems okay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outer dimension is just `len(x)` where `x` is the slice of slices you pass to the function (your example `[][]float64{{11, 5, 14, 1}, {11, 5, 14, 1}}`).
However, the inner dimensions are not guaranteed to be equal so you will have to go through each element and check what `len` they have.

If you have the guarantee than each element of `x` has the same number of elements, just find `len(x[0])` if `len(x) > 0`.

Comment: I know. I am more concerned about an n-dimensional case.

Comment: @ArafatK the same reasoning applies for  any number of dimensions. A slice of slices (of slices...) is not a matrix, in mathematical sense. The lengths of inners slices can be different; they can even change.

Answer (score 1):

Go only provides 1-dimensional arrays and slices.  N-dimensional arrays can be emulated by using arrays of arrays, which is close to what what you're doing--you have a 1-dimensional slice, which contains 2 1-dimensional slices.

This is problematic, because slices are not of a defined length.  So you could end up with slices of wildly different lengths:

```
[][]float64{
    {1, 2, 3, 4},
    {5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10},
}
```

If you use actual arrays, this is simpler, because arrays have a fixed length:

`[2][4]float64`

You can extend this to as many dimensions as you want:

`[2][4][8]float64` provides three dimensions, with respective depths of 2, 4, and 8.

Then you can tell the capacity of each dimension by using the built-in `len()` function on any of the elements:

```
foo := [2][4][7]float64{}
x := len(foo)       // x == 2
y := len(foo[0])    // y == 4
z := len(foo[0][0]) // z == 8
```